# Searching by RegExp (Total Commander / PHP)

Tags: php, regex, search, total-commander

I'm using Total Commander (file manager), which allows searching file content by regular expressions.

I'd like to search PHP files for deprecated syntax like `$_SESSION[user]` - so, I need the RegExp for finding all tags, which don't have quotes inside the square brackets.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Problems with escaping, or don't know how to match letters?

Comment: What if `user` was a defined constant ?

Comment: `SESSION\[[^'](\w+)\]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is assuming you don't have defined constants:
`\$\w+\[\s*(?:[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+(?:"|')|(?:"|')[a-zA-Z]+)\s*\]`

**Explanation:**

- `\$` : match `$`
- `\w+` : match `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` one or more times
- `\[` : match `[`
- `\s*` : match white spaces zero or more times
- `(?:[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+(?:"|')|(?:"|')[a-zA-Z]+)` : match `"` or `'` followed by letters, or just letters, or letters followed by `'` or `"`
- `\s*` : match white spaces zero or more times
- `\]` : match `]`

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/oE0pY1)

> <sub>**Disclaimer:** This will *not validate* your variables for example `$0[aaa]` would be matched.</sub>